# In Plotly, using HTML, why do some Greek letters work with decimal but not with entity name?

Tags: python, html, plotly

In my Plotly figure title I need to use Greek letters and for some letters I can use the entity name directly as:
`&mu;` and it renders the correct Greek letter mu. However when I do the same for omega or psi with `&omega;` or `&psi;` then I just get the word written in Latin characters with the '&' and ';' but not the corresponding Greek one. Here is an image of the result:

[image]

However, using the decimal codes work as intended: `layout = go.Layout(title='&#969; #968;')`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I *think* it has something to do with javascript backend, and in particular `entityToUnicode` in [svg_text_utils.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/662f51ae27989f171ca0e7210f105aa065217ed3/src/lib/svg_text_utils.js#L389).

So I think `$mu;` is the only greek letter that will work (because it's specifically being handled by `entityToUnicode` along with a hand full of other characters).

From svg_text_utils.js:

```js
/*
 * N.B. HTML entities are listed without the leading '&' and trailing ';'
 * https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html
 *
 * FWIW if we wanted to support the full set, it has 2261 entries:
 * https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/entities.json
 * though I notice that some of these are duplicates and/or are missing ";"
 * eg: "&amp;", "&amp", "&AMP;", and "&AMP" all map to "&"
 * We no longer need to include numeric entities here, these are now handled
 * by String.fromCodePoint/fromCharCode
 *
 * Anyway the only ones that are really important to allow are the HTML special
 * chars <, >, and &, because these ones can trigger special processing if not
 * replaced by the corresponding entity.
 */
var entityToUnicode = {
    mu: 'μ',
    amp: '&',
    lt: '<',
    gt: '>',
    nbsp: ' ',
    times: '×',
    plusmn: '±',
    deg: '°'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. In light of this, it makes it seem that the hint "You can guess the code for other greek letters" after giving just the code for mu on plotly's website is a joke. Here is the corresponding page: https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/

Comment: It looks like for some things it will work, for instance in ChartStudio it worked for annotations, although the `&XXX;` format is not really preserved (toggling back and forth between rich text and html).  see [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~jayveesea/1/#/).